Manga where the main character has terrible eyesight due to a curse from a dragon, so he ends up wandering down deeper into a dungeon
I can't remember the name of this manga, but I do remember that the female main character will eventually meet up with the main character deep inside the dungeon, and she also ends up having a terrible sense of direction.

Is this My Blade Will Lead the Way! Abandoned in a Labyrinth as a Directionally Challenged S-Rank Swordsman...?

The swordsman, Jir, had just joined a well-known S-rank party when he finds himself stranded all alone in the hardest labyrinth. Normally, there's no way to survive such a situation other than to wait for rescue. Relying on nothing but his heroic sword skills, Jir decides to escape on his own! "Heh! You're all bark and no bite, Labyrinth!" he boldly declares. Due to his extremely poor sense of direction, he's completely unaware that he's headed towards the deepest level where the labyrinth boss awaits!!

The protagonist, Jir, is a bespectacled swordsman who was cursed with poor eyesight as the result of slaying a dragon.



While raiding a labyrinth with a party of adventurers he was hired to assist, he falls through the floor, breaking his glasses, and is abandoned by his party. He tries to find his way out of the labyrinth on his own, but is unable to, due to his poor eyesight and sense of direction.
After three months of being lost in the labyrinth, he meets and befriends a saintess named Lilyleah, who also got separated from her party and lost. They agree to try and find their way out together, but it turns out that she too has a poor sense of direction, so instead of ascending out of the labyrinth, they spend the next month unintentionally descending fifty levels deeper into it.




This sounds like a horrible yet also hilarious situation to be in.
